# iOS: sync data to calendar works in main thread, but *may* not work within dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, eventkit

Basically I want to sync some events in my app to iOS calendar. Ideally it should be done in a background thread so users don't notice. When it's done in the main thread, everything works fine; but when wrapped within dispatch_async, sometimes (not every time) it can stop during the `saveEvent` method (where I added a comment to mark the line). It may not work in this build, but works in a new build. This is really weired... Anyone seen similar issue?

My code is roughly like this:

```
- (void)synchronousTravelToCalendar
{
    if ([tooles SynchronousCalendar])
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
            [Calendar removeCalendar];
            [Calendar addCalendar];
            // resetClendar iterates over the list of events 
            //  and add them to calendar one by one
            [self resetClendar:[tripList travelList]];
        });
   }
}
```

function `resetClendar` calls the following function to add an event

```
+ (BOOL)addEventAt:(NSDate *)startDate endAt:(NSDate *)endDate withTitle:                   (NSString *)title inLocation:(NSString *)location
{    
    EKEvent * event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];


    event.calendar = myCalendar;
    event.location = location;
    event.title = title;
    event.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"lvxingjia://www.lvxingjia.cc"];

    event.startDate = startDate;
    if (endDate == nil){
        event.endDate = [startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60 * 30];
    } else {
        event.endDate = endDate;
    }

    //with dispatch_async, the following call is not completed
    BOOL result = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:nil];    

    if (result)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }  
}
```

Comment: What mechanism are you using to ensure the thread safety of your calendar object?

Comment: @ipmcc why there is thread-safety issue for calendar? all the delete/create operations are sequential within dispatch_async. Do you mean the saveEvent method is implemented asynchronously and can cause thread-unsafe conditions?

Comment: OK, finally sort it out. We need to modify the code with     BOOL result = [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:NO error:nil]; then do a batch commit outside of the for-loop. The problem is gone with this approach.